# How to remove optgroup while leaving options

Tags: javascript, jquery, optgroup

Can anyone please explain why jQuery works on the original code but deletes all the option for my code.

```
var i=0;
var cursel = "#mySelect".concat(i);
$(cursel).children().remove("optgroup");
```

Original Code:
http://jsfiddle.net/frJEq/

My Code:
http://jsfiddle.net/frJEq/43/

I have multiple of the exact same select menu so that's why I have it setup for the concat to put in the counter. But why does it work for the original and not mine? I have been pouring over code and examples and can't see why.

Comment: actually your code structure is different from it

Comment: Oh wow, I feel like a fool now. Okay, then is there a way to extract the options from within the optgroups and delete the optgroups, leaving all the options how they were. Like I said, I have been trying to work with the DOM model to move them around, to no avail.

Comment: Why does this skip some of them? http://jsfiddle.net/DTdvJ/1/

Comment: It skips items because you are removing items from a list while you are iterating over the list with a for loop. That is generally not something you want to do. See my answer below for a line of code that works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does run. Most of your options are inside optgroup elements, so they get removed. Try moving the options outside of the optgroup elements, like in your "original code" snippet.

What you want to do is use the unwrap method:

```
$(cursel).children('optgroup').children().unwrap();
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/